# Tri-Diagonal Matrix in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, matrix, diagonal

[The array data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQrRj.png)

In using cubic spline interpolation, I need to solve a tri-diagonal matrix to get the coefficients. Given four arrays ( first 3 are the diagonals of the matrix, and the fourth is the vector b for A^-1*b = x), I want to return an array that will be my M-values. Once I have the M-values I can calculate the coefficients.

I am pretty unfamiliar with VBA so I am not sure that I am passing the arrays correctly, but my code is as follows:

```
Function DiagSolv(a() As Variant, b() As Variant, c() As Variant, d() As Variant) As Variant

Dim N As Double

N = 9  

c(1, 1) = c(1, 1) / b(1, 1)

d(1, 1) = d(1, 1) / b(1, 1)

d(N, 1) = (d(N, 1) - a(N, 1) * d(N - 1, 1)) / (b(N, 1) - a(N, 1) * c(N - 1, 1))

Dim temp As Double

For i = 2 To N - 1 Step 1
    temp = b(i, 1) - a(i, 1) * c(i - 1, 1)
    c(i, 1) = c(i, 1) / temp
    d(i, 1) = (d(i, 1) - a(i, 1) * d(i - 1, 1)) / temp
Next i

Dim x(8, 0) As Variant

x(N - 1, 0) = d(N, 1)

For J = N - 1 To 1 Step -1
    x(J - 1, 0) = d(J, 1) - c(J, 1) * x(J, 0)
Next J

DiagSolv = x()

End Function

Sub Solver()

Dim ArrayA() As Variant
ArrayA = Range("AH39:AH47").Value

Dim ArrayB() As Variant
ArrayB = Range("AI39:AI47").Value

Dim ArrayC() As Variant
ArrayC = Range("AJ39:AJ47").Value

Dim ArrayD() As Variant
ArrayD = Range("AK39:AK47").Value

Dim m() As Variant

m() = DiagSolv(ArrayA, ArrayB, ArrayC, ArrayD)

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the *problem* you're having?  Do you get an error message?  What does it do *instead* of work?

Comment: I just get #VALUE! when I call the function

Comment: Try calling the function from a Sub instead - that will give you a more-useful error message.

Comment: From what I can see I get a type mismatch when I divide c(i)/temp. Do i need temp As Variant ?

Comment: What are `c(i)` and `temp` when it errors?

Comment: Remove the `()` from the `Dim` statement. `Dim temp As Double`

Comment: Thank you @ScottCraner that was causing the type mismatch. I changed the function to a variant type and the variable x() to a variant type as well so I am returning the same type. I now get an error saying the subscript is out of range for the fourth line c(1) = c(1)/b(1). Any ideas?

Comment: Well without seeing the data inputs it is hard to know.  you will need to look into the Locals window to ensure that the arrays have an item at that location.

Comment: Looking at my locals window...the a,b,c,d arrays seem to all have the values that I had input on my worksheet. I posted the data above.

Comment: Ive also added in my Sub for reference

Comment: Your `ArrayA`, etc in the calling sub are 2-D arrays (1 to 9, 1 to 1), so you need to account for that.

Comment: Thanks Tim I recently realized that the 2-D arrays were the problem and was finally able to get a solution.

Comment: Edited in the resolved code